# How to Prove this Multiset Identity by Combinatorial Proof

Tags: factorial, combinatorial-proofs, multisets

I was wondering how to do a combinatorial proof of the following identity: $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\bigr)$= $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n-1}{k}\!\!\bigr)$ + $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n}{k-1}\!\!\bigr)$  for all n, k ∈ N and not both equals to 0. The image of the question is here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKuNr.png)

A multiset is an unordered list of elements, repeats allowed. A multiset will be denoted
M = h. . .i to distinguish it from an ordinary set.
One can more formally define a multiset M to be a pair (X, m), where X is a set and m : X → N≥1
is a function. m is the multiplicity function, recording how many times a given element of the set X is
included in the multiset M. So for example, if X = {a, b, c} and m(a) = 2, m(b) = 1, m(c) = 3, then
M = ha, a, b, c, c, ci.
2
Just as looking at k-element subsets of a set of size n gives rise to the binomial coefficients, we can investigate interesting counting problems using the notion of multisets of a certain size.

Example Question:
Denote by $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\bigr)$
the number of k-element multisubsets of a set of size n.
If n = 2, consider the set X = {a, b}. Then the set of multisubsets of X of size 2 is
{⟨a,a⟩,⟨a,b⟩,⟨b,b⟩}, and the set of multisubsets of size 3 is {⟨a,a,a⟩,⟨a,a,b⟩,⟨a,b,b⟩,⟨b,b,b⟩}. Thus $\bigl(\!\!\binom{2}{2}\!\!\bigr)$ = 3 and $\bigl(\!\!\binom{2}{3}\!\!\bigr)$  = 4

Comment: The information in the image you linked is contained in a single sentence. Could you write it instead? Also, the symbols in question are different than the binomial coefficients. You can type `$\bigl(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\bigr)$` to make it appear instead of `$\binom{n}{k}$`.

Comment: Thank you for your sincere review, I will change it immediately.

Comment: @shoteyes Do you think the question is ok now?

Comment: No. C(n, k - 1) should be C(n -1, k - 1).

Comment: @Mick based on the OP’s title and image linked, this question seems to be about the *multiset* coefficients not the binomial coefficients.

Comment: @shoteyes yes it is a multiset question and i also try to do it like binomial equation, as Mick has did but then it didn't work

Comment: @shoteyes do you have any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: @shoteyes I added the specific definition but I'm not sure how it relates to the Pascal's identity

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a combinatorial proof:

Let $x$ be one of the $n$ distinct elements of the underlying set $S$. The multisubsets of size $k$ can be partitioned into two different groups:

- The ones that include *at least one* copy of $x$, and
- The ones that don’t include $x$ at all.

The first group has $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n}{k-1}\!\!\bigr)$ multisubsets in it, because taking out one copy of $x$ corresponds uniquely to an arbitrary multisubset of $S$ of size $k - 1$.

The second group has $\bigl(\!\!\binom{n - 1}{k}\!\!\bigr)$ multisubsets in it, because these are the multisubsets of size $k$ with underlying set $S\setminus \{x\}$ which has $n - 1$ elements.

Therefore,

$$
\biggl(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\!\biggr) = \biggl(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k - 1}\!\!\!\biggr) + \biggl(\!\!\!\binom{n - 1}{k}\!\!\!\biggr).
$$

Comment: @MuratSina you can make a table using this recurrence formula, but it will be an infinite rectangle in both directions not an infinite triangle. Pascal’s triangle *is* a triangle because $k$ has to satisfy $0\leq k\leq n$ for binomial coefficients, but for multiset coefficients we can have $k > n$. The only restriction for $k$ is that $k\geq 0$.

Comment: oh okay, thank you @shoteyes

Answer (score 1):

Let X be a particular person in the group of n.

We are supposed to choose k members from that group and this is C(n, k).

To complete the above selection, we can split the selection by

either with X as a must (i.e. C(n - 1, k - 1)).... [X is already a member, we only need to choose k - 1 persons from the remaining n - 1 group.]

OR

must exclude X (i.e. C(n - 1, k)).....[X must not be chosen, there are n - 1 candidates availble and need to choose k.]

Added: X is either selected as a member or NOT as a member. The two events are mutally exclusive. Thus, "OR"ing the two events end up with C(n - 1, k - 1) + C(n - 1, k). This is exactly C(n, k).

Comment: @MuratSina SEe added and further explanations and the comments inside the square brackets]

Comment: @MuratSina Upvoting can be done later when you have enough qualification. The important point is whether the content is helpful or not.